# Saved Jupiter notebook to strange format

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have been learning python for a year. Yesterday I was working on a project for many hours, and I was constantly clicking the save button. In the end, I tried to download the notebook as a pdf file unsuccessfully, but it was very late and gave up.

Today I went to the Jupyter notebook and 2/3 of the work was not there!. It says last checkpoint 19 pm but I went to sleep (and saved the file numerous times) at 4 am.

On the other hand, I am finding a lot of files with format .1 (never seen this before) with the name of the original file, however, when I open them I see endless lines of JSON code of what I believe is the work I was doing yesterday, just in an unworkable format.

[THis is a capture of the type of file I saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuKXG.jpg)

Does anybody know what happened here and what I can do to recover the original code?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The file in the screenshot looks like a Jupyter file (Jupyter notebooks are saved in the JSON format). Try to change the extension to `.ipynb` and open it in Jupyter Notebook.